# How to use Pentaho Data Integration (Spoon 4.4) for Star Modeling

Tags: pentaho

I'm looking for a tool to build a Mondrian's cube XML description file to use over my Star Schema (one fact table and 4 dimensions tables directly link to the fact table).

I'm a bit lost, browsing tutorial doesn't help since they seem to be about another version than mine. Mine doesn't include the `Star Model` perspective, I just have a `Model` perspective.

My feeling is that this `Model` perspective is just useful to build Mondrian cube for a flat model (with just one big fact table). I would be glad if someone could confirm that. But my main demand is : how to build a Star Model description schema (with Pentaho's tool) ? If there's a missing plugin, how to install it ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to download a separate tool for the moment called schema workbench. Get it from the mondrian not pentaho project on SourceForge.

This tool will be replaced by something new in the next 6 months but it does what you need and has handy validation built in

Comment: Ugly but effective tool ! Thank you !

Comment: yup! but with the validation it provides and most of the functionality I think it's better than hand crafting a mondrian xml schema!

Comment: I agree but the UI library used put my computer back to 1996 ;)